# how to put a char[][] into jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm having difficulty displaying a 2d dimensional char array into a jTable.
I'm using netbeans.

Can someone guide me on how to put:
char[][] wordSet;

into a jTable.

Getting the error

That's the error I get

`(argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to TableModel) constructor JTable.JTable(int,int) is not applicable (argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to int) constructor JTable. JTable(Vector,Vector) is not applicable (argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to Vector) constructor JTable. JTable(Object[][],Object[]) is not applicable (argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to Object[][])`

After using:

```
JTable table = new JTable(w.getPuzzleSet(), "Puzzle");
```

Comment: You won't learn anything if you don't make an effort.

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Also, [here's the obligatory link to a tutorial on JTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: Thats the error I get

      (argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to TableModel)
    constructor JTable.JTable(int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to int)
    constructor JTable.JTable(Vector,Vector) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to Vector)
    constructor JTable.JTable(Object[][],Object[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; char[][] cannot be converted to Object[][])

After using:
JTable table = new JTable(w.getPuzzleSet(), "Puzzle");

Comment: @user3131312: You should probably add that error and the code that's causing that error to your post.

Comment: JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)

I passed Char[][] data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Object instead of char. eg. instead of

```
char[][] charTable = {{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'d', 'e','f'}};
```

Use

```
Object[][] charTable = {{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'d', 'e','f'}};
```

As @nachokk noted, you can also use `Character`

```
Character[][] charTable = {{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'d', 'e','f'}};
```

A `char[][]` is not the same as `Object[][]` as `char` is a primitive. `JTable` has constructor using `Object[][]` and `Vector`, no `char[][]`

**example**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CharTable extends JPanel{
    private static final int DIM_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int DIM_HEIGHT = 500;

    Object[][] charTable = {{'a', 'b', 'c'},{'d', 'e','f'}};
    String[] colNames = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};

    public CharTable(){
        add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(charTable, colNames)));
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new CharTable());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(DIM_WIDTH, DIM_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I convert my existing charTable to Object type

Comment: Just use the object type

Comment: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?242750-Java-Word-Search-Puzzle

I am using this, but want to display the data in the form of a table

Comment: @peeskillet You can use `Character[][]`

Comment: @user3131312 do what nachokk said

Comment: if(puzzle[row][col] == ' ' || puzzle[row][col] == word.charAt(i)) {
     puzzle[row][col] = word.charAt(i);

If I use Character type, how should I change this if statement accordingly please?

Comment: the chars will get auto-boxed.

Comment: side note, should I delete this question?

Comment: @user3131312 no, just mark as correct peeskillet answer

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your char[][] to Object[][] by doing something like this:

```
char[][] wordSet = { {'a', 'b'},{'c', 'd'} };
String[] header = {"one", "two"};

Object[][] objectSet = new Object[wordSet.length][wordSet[0].length];

for (int i = 0; i < wordSet.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < wordSet[0].length; j ++) {
        objectSet[i][j] = wordSet[i][j];
    }
}

JTable table = new JTable(objectSet, header);
```

Comment: how would you create a table without column names,
JTable table = new JTable(objectSet, ?);

Comment: table.setTableHeader(null);